# Subsetting graph based on a path with correct sequence

Tags: r, igraph

Given is following graph:

```
g= graph.formula(A -+ B,
                 B -+ C,
                 A -+ C,
                 B -+ D,
                 C -+ D
)
plot(g)
```

[image]

The overall target is to split the graph into all simple subgraphs. In my current approach I am gathering all simple paths from root `"A"` to leave `"D"`.

```
paths= all_simple_paths(g, from = "A", to = "D")
```

Then I generate all subgraphs of graph `g` based on those `paths`.

```
sg= lapply(paths, function(x) induced_subgraph(g, x))
```

Although `paths[[1]]` contains the vertex sequence of path `"A" "B" "C" "D"` the first subgraph `sg[[1]]` does not follow the path's sequence exactly:

```
IGRAPH DN-- 4 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] A->B A->C B->C B->D C->D
```

[image]

**Problem:**

`sg[[1]]` contains 2 edges `A->C, B->D` too much. I understand `igraphs` `induced_subgraph()` function works correctly as it chooses the provided vertices, while ignoring the sequnce as further constraint.

**Question:**

How can I subset `g` into all simple graphs based on `paths` following exactly the vertex sequence?

Comment:

My overarching target to split the graph into all simple subgraphs cannot be achieved by `get.all.shortest.paths()` as it will not find `paths[[1]]` with `"A" "B" "C" "D"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g= graph.formula(A -+ B,
                 B -+ C,
                 A -+ C,
                 B -+ D,
                 C -+ D
)
coords <- layout.auto(g)
rownames(coords) <- V(g)$name

paths <- all_simple_paths(g, from = "A", to = "D")
sg <- lapply(paths, function(x) subgraph.edges(g, get.edge.ids(g, x[tail(head(rep(seq(x), each = 2), -1), -1)])))

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
invisible(lapply(c(list(g), sg), function(x) plot(x, layout = coords[V(x)$name, ])))
```

[image]